# C++/cli regarding setting a unmanaged pointer in a managed property

Tags: c++-cli

Say I have a c++ struct:

```
typedef struct CStruct {
   char * data;
} CStruct;
```

Say I have a pointer to the C++ struct in a managed class in C++/cli, which has a property that references the struct's member:

```
public ref class ManagedClass 
{
public:
   CStruct * theStruct;
   ManagedClass(CStruct * strucPtr){ 
       this->theStruct = strucPtr; 
   }
   property String ^ data {
      String ^ get() {
         return gcnew String(theStruct->data);
      }
      void set(String ^ val)
      {
          IntPtr marshalToCharStar = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(val);
          char * strPtr = static_cast<char *>(marshalToCharStar.ToPointer());
          delete theStruct->data;
          theStruct->data = strPtr;
          Marshal::FreeHGlobal(marshalToCharStar);
      }
   }
}
```

First of all, is the marshaling done correctly?  Should not have problems with the garbage collector here right?  Secondly, is getting/setting an unmanaged object using properties a good idea?  Any downfalls to that?

Right now I have an object similar to the one described, but member values are disappearing/becoming garbage, and I am trying to eliminate possible causes.

Appreciate the help

Comment: No, that is not correct.  The Marshal::FreeHGlobal() call is wrong, that produces a dangling pointer bug.  That makes the delete operator questionable as well.  You have to use the same allocator that was used to create the strucPtr->data pointer that was passed in the constructor call, we can't see it.  And you have to fret about a leak when the managed object gets garbage-collected, you'd need a finalizer if the managed object "owns" the pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Should I move the freeHGlobal to the finalize (I do have a finalize in my actual class, sorry about not including it) ? The allocator I use for all my pointers is new, so delete still questionable?

Comment: Feel free to make an answer similar to your comment and I will accept it

Comment: I only know what is wrong, the question does not have enough info to tell how to do it right.  Just complete the Q+A by yourself.